# Convert List[A] to List[Option[A]] depending on A members

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have defined:

```
final case class EventOpt(start: Option[Long], end: Option[Long])
final case class Event(start: Long, end: Long)
```

The only interesting objects for me are those with both fields set and I want to filter the rest

Having `List[EventOpt]` I'd like to convert it to `List[Option[Event]]` using `Some(Event)` when both `start` and `end` are set and `None` when either of `start` and `end` them is `None`?

Eg.

```
List(EventOpt(Some(1), None), EventOpt(None, Some(2)), EventOpt(Some(3), Some(4))) 
=>
List(None, None, Some(Event(4, 3)))
```

By doing so, it will allow be to do a simple `flatMap` over the last list and omit the `None`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a separate `flatMap` step, simply `collect` only what you need right away:

```
eventOpts.collect { case EventOpt(Some(x), Some(y)) => Event(x, y) }
```